# Can golang benchmark give a custom output?

Tags: go, benchmarking

I'm benchmarking code with different list sizes (lists of size S)  Go benchmark shows ns/op but what I want is (ns/op)/S.

In other words, the output of `go test -bench=.` is:

```
BenchmarkMy10-4         100000000           15.7 ns/op
BenchmarkMy20-4         50000000            33.8 ns/op
BenchmarkMy30-4         30000000            43.8 ns/op
BenchmarkMy40-4         30000000            49.3 ns/op
BenchmarkMy50-4         30000000            56.6 ns/op
BenchmarkMy1000-4        2000000           686 ns/op
BenchmarkMy10000-4        200000          6685 ns/op
BenchmarkMy100000-4        20000         65425 ns/op
```

The "10" in "My10" represents a list of 10 items (S=10).

While it is useful to know the ns/op for different list sizes, I would also like to know the ns/op/S (time per item in the list).

Right now I'm pasting the results into a spreadsheet and doing the math there. However I'd like to have "go test" output this information for me.

My main_test.go file looks like:

```
import "testing"

var result int

func benchmarkMy(i int, b *testing.B) {
  var r int
  mylist := MakeList(i)
  b.ResetTimer()
  for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
    r = My(mylist)
  }
  result = r
}

func BenchmarkMy10(b *testing.B)         { benchmarkMy(10, b) }
func BenchmarkMy20(b *testing.B)         { benchmarkMy(20, b) }
func BenchmarkMy30(b *testing.B)         { benchmarkMy(30, b) }
func BenchmarkMy40(b *testing.B)         { benchmarkMy(40, b) }
func BenchmarkMy50(b *testing.B)         { benchmarkMy(50, b) }
func BenchmarkMy1000(b *testing.B)       { benchmarkMy(1000, b) }
func BenchmarkMy10000(b *testing.B)      { benchmarkMy(10000, b) }
func BenchmarkMy100000(b *testing.B)     { benchmarkMy(100000, b) }
```

It seems like the test.BenchmarkResult structure has the information I need, but I don't see how to use this structure.

Comment: No, stdandard Benchmark cannot do this simply because it is not generally useful. ns/op/S might be interesting for algorithms which are O(1) only.

Comment: @Volker why it wouldn't be useful to output custom results, i.e. track other values? What if someone wanted to measure compression ratio?

Comment: @kravemir Since Go 1.13 you _can_ report custom metrics, but this is of limited use and your example of compression ration seems strange (unless we are talking about a randomized algorithm).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write a custom benchmark using [Benchmark](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark) function from package `testing`. And get a `BenchmarkResult` instance you mention.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func benchmarkMy(i int) {
    fn := func(b *testing.B) {
         // Code you want benchmarked
    }
    r := testing.Benchmark(fn)

    fmt.Printf("%d ns/op\n", int(r.T)/r.N)
    fmt.Printf("%d ns/op/i\n", int(r.T)/r.N/i)
}

func main() {
    benchmarkMy(10)
}
```

You'll have to put this in a different package and run with `go run` instead of `go test`.

Check an example in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hWk6QnicEP).

Comment: I haven't done this before and couldn't find much supporting documents. To me this seems to be the way to do it.